# SharePoint Online, "Dec 31 [this Year]" calculated field - how?

Tags: calculated-column, date-time, calculated-column-formula

Trying to create calculated field for SPD workflow. There should be yearly reminder (I wanted to compare "Date workflow started" with this field..).

Tried to create Date field/Calculated field with this formula but no result(field is empty)

```
=DATE(Year([Today]),12,31)
```

Maybe somebody did the same before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculated Columns are evaluated on item modification, not on viewing. So `[Today]` is not an allowed value.

However, you can use this formula to get the 12/31 of the upcoming year:

```
=DATE(Year([Modified]),12,31)
```

You could also use `[Created]` depending on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Thank You for response! I know, but in my case I need [Today], because next year it will show wrong information(in 2019 it will still be '2018-12-31').. Uff..